# Which integration rule is applied here?

Tags: integration

i have a derivation of a physical equation, where there is an equation

$$\int mv \gamma \,\textrm{d}v = \frac{m}{2}\int \gamma \, \textrm{d}(v^2)$$

**Q1:** How did we derive right side from left one? Could anyone explain this step by step or provide me with names of the integration rules applied here so i can google it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{dv^2}{dv}=2v \Rightarrow \frac{dv^2}2=vdv
$$

Comment: Thanks... a simple derivation explains everything.

Comment: In fact sometimes it is easier to me to learn integration through diferentiation.

Answer (score 3):

This follows directly from

$$\int A f(x)\, \text dx= A\int f(x)\, \text dx$$

and a substitution.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'll mention that $\mbox{d}(v^2)$ is shorthand for $\dfrac{\mbox{d}v^2}{\mbox{d}v}\mbox{d}v$.

Comment: What yo just said is that i can put a constant in front of an integral? TY

Comment: @71GA $m$ is just a constant.  Thus you can move it out of the integral.